# How to close Unity without closing the entire app when changing fragments in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-fragments

I have an app that the user can go through different fragments using BottomNavigationView and one of those fragments is a Unity3D application. So when i open the Unity fragment it works but when i open another fragment and open the Unity fragment back it crashes how do i fix this here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
NavController mNavController;
NavDestination mDestination;
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
String tab;
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    boolean b = this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.top_menu_custom, null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(customView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


    mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    ImageButton profileButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    ImageButton notificationButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.noti_button);

    profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,profileFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(tab)
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .commit();
            mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NotificationFragment notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,notificationFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(tab)
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .commit();
            mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    mBottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    mBottomNavigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.black)));

    mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard,R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_card,R.id.navigation_deals)
            .build();

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBottomNavigationView, mNavController);
    mNavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDestination = mNavController.getCurrentDestination();
            tab = mDestination.toString();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mDestination.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        mNavController.navigate(mDestination.getId());
        mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

UnityMapFragment

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment{

protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
FrameLayout frameLayoutForUnity;

public MapFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    this.frameLayoutForUnity = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutForUnity);
    this.frameLayoutForUnity.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(),
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

// Quit Unity
@Override
public void onDestroy ()
{
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: `it crashes how do i fix this` could you please post your stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to make a solution for this problem don't know if its good to make it this way or not but what i did was I instantiate the UnityPlayer in my MainActivity and in my fragment i call upon the UnityPlayer that was instatiated in my Main Activity.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
public NavController mNavController;
public NavDestination mDestination;
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
String tab;
int onBackTimes = 0;

public UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; <----Call unity player

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this); <----UNITY PLAYER HERE

    boolean b = this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.top_menu_custom, null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(customView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


    mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    ImageButton profileButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    ImageButton notificationButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.noti_button);

    profileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,profileFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(tab)
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .commit();
            mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NotificationFragment notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,notificationFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(tab)
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .commit();
            mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    mBottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    mBottomNavigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.black)));

    mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard,R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_card,R.id.navigation_deals)
            .build();

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBottomNavigationView, mNavController);
    mNavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            mDestination = mNavController.getCurrentDestination();
            tab = mDestination.toString();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    onBackTimes +=1;

    if(onBackTimes>1){
        LoginActivity.close.finish();
        finish();

    }
    else{
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onBackPressed();
        mNavController.navigate(mDestination.getId());
    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            onBackTimes=0;
        }
    }, 2000);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


//UNITY STUFF OVER HERE

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

@Override protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

UnityMapFragment

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment{

private MainActivity mUnityMainActivity;
private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

public MapFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //this code calls the UNITYPLAYER from MainActivity and return it here
    mUnityMainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    View unityPlayViewer = mUnityMainActivity.mUnityPlayer.getView();
    mUnityMainActivity.mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    mUnityMainActivity.mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);

    return unityPlayViewer;
}

/** FOR UNITY **/
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mUnityMainActivity.mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

// Resume Unity
@Override public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityMainActivity.mUnityPlayer.resume();
}
```

I don't know why i have to include the OnPause, OnResume etc on both file but if one of them doesn't have it it'll crash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, a new UnityPlayer is being created every-time we switch to the unity fragment and this crashes the app. So we need to create the UnityPlayer only for the first time or only when the player has been stopped. This works on my side.

In the UnityFragment class, my global variables :

```
protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
private View view;
private FrameLayout frameLayoutForUnity;
```

In `onCreate` a new UnityPlayer is created, which is called only for the first time :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity()); // create Unity Player
}
```

In `onCreateView` we refresh the view for UnityPlayer :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mUnityPlayer.getParent() != null){
        ((ViewGroup)mUnityPlayer.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unity, container, false);
    this.frameLayoutForUnity = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.unityFragmentLayout);
    this.frameLayoutForUnity.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(),
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);
    return view;
}
```

Rest remains same. There could be better solutions than this. Cheers :)